# Void pointers in C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I have written this qsort:

```
void qsort(void *a[],int low,int high, int (*compare)(void*,void*));
```

When I call this on

```
char *strarr[5];
```

It says invalid conversion from char** to void**. Why this is wrong?

This is the code:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

inline void strswap(void *a,void *b) {
    char *t=*(char**)a;
    *(char**)a=*(char**)b;
    *(char**)b=t;
}

int strcompare(void *a, void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(char**)a,*(char**)b);
}

void qsort1(void *a[],int low,int high, int (*compare)(void*,void*), void (*swap)(void*,void*)) {
    if(low>=high)
        return;
    int q=low-1;
    for(int i=low;i<=high-1;i++)
        if((*compare)(&a[i],&a[high]) < 0)
            swap(&a[i],&a[++q]);
    swap(&a[high],&a[++q]);
    qsort1(a,low,q-1,compare,swap);
    qsort1(a,q+1,high,compare,swap);
}

int main() {
    const  int n=3;
    //int a[n]={4,6,8,12,10,9,8,0,24,3};
    char *strarr[5]={"abcd","zvb","cax"};
    qsort1(strarr,0,n-1,strcompare,strswap);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << strarr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why have you tagged this as C?

Comment: Wow, when saying "Why is this wrong?" then I could list *so many things*.

Comment: @DeadMG is correct. Learn about `std::vector`, `std::string` and `std::sort`. If you need help converting your code to real modern C++, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An implicit conversion from any pointer type to `void *` is allowed, because `void *` is a defined to be a pointer type that has a sufficient range that it can represent any value that any other pointer type can.  (Technically, only other *object* pointer types, which excludes pointers to functions).

This does not mean that `void *` has the same size or representation as any other pointer type, though: Converting a pointer from another pointer type to a `void *` *does not necessarily leave the underlying representation unchanged*.  Converting from `double *` to `void *` is just like converting from `double` to `int` - it has to happen in full view of the compiler, you can't hide that conversion behind the compiler's back.

So this implies that while `void *` is a generic pointer, `void **` is *not* a generic pointer-to-pointer.  It's a pointer to `void *` - a `void **` pointer should only ever point to real `void *` objects (whereas `void *` itself can point to anything).

This is why there's no implicit conversions between `type **` and `void **` - it's for the same reason that there's no implicit conversions between `double *` and `int *`.

Now, there is one special case: for historical reasons, `char *` is guaranteed to have the same size, representation and alignment requirements as `void *`.  This means that conversions between `char **` (in particular) and `void **` are actually OK, as an exception to the general rule.  So in your *particular* case, your code is correct if you add a cast to `void **` when you pass `strarr` to `qsort1()`.

However, your `qsort1()` is only defined to correctly work on arrays of `void *` or `char *` (including `unsigned char *` etc.).  You can't use it to sort an array of `double *` pointers, for example (although it would actually work on most common environments today).

Answer (score 10):

Any pointer can be implicitly converted to a void pointer. But your first parameter *isn't* a void pointer - it's an array of void pointers, and there is no implicit conversion to that. You probably want to declare your function as:

```
void qsort(void *,int low,int high, int (*compare)(void*,void*));
```

but it's difficult to say without seeing the code.